# How to serve a file using iron router or meteor itself?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm trying to serve a zip file on my Meteor app but I'm stuck. After a lot of Googling it seems the best way to go is with Iron Router but I don't know how:

```
Router.map ->
  @route "data",
    where: 'server'
    path: '/data/:id'
    action: ->
      data = getBase64ZipData(this.params.id)
      this.response.writeHead 200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/zip;base64' }
      ???
```

Comment: does putting the file into the `public` folder not work for some reason?

Comment: ahhh coffeescript! can not read it as fast as regular js

Answer (score 34, accepted):

#### On the server:

```js
var fs = Npm.require('fs');

var fail = function(response) {
  response.statusCode = 404;
  response.end();
};

var dataFile = function() {
  // TODO write a function to translate the id into a file path
  var file = fileFromId(this.params.id);

  // Attempt to read the file size
  var stat = null;
  try {
    stat = fs.statSync(file);
  } catch (_error) {
    return fail(this.response);
  }

  // The hard-coded attachment filename
  var attachmentFilename = 'filename-for-user.zip';

  // Set the headers
  this.response.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'application/zip',
    'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=' + attachmentFilename
    'Content-Length': stat.size
  });

  // Pipe the file contents to the response
  fs.createReadStream(file).pipe(this.response);
};

Router.route('/data/:id', dataFile, {where: 'server'});
```

#### On the client:

```html
<a href='/data/123'>download zip</a>
```

The nice part about this is that it will download the file as an attachment, and you can customize the filename that the user sees. The trick is writing the `fileFromId` function. I find it's easiest to store all of my dynamically generated files under `/tmp`.

This answer assumes that the files are being generated dynamically. If you want to serve static content, you can just put your files under the `public` directory. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21341291/how-to-serve-static-content-images-fonts-etc-using-iron-router) question for more details.

Comment: How to verify the identity of the caller on the server route?

Comment: The server route won't be able to identify the user via meteor's authentication mechanisms. You'd need to introduce cookies or some other sort of exchange.