# How do I serve a file from S3 through Meteor Iron Router

Tags: amazon-s3, meteor, iron-router

My question is very similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21565991/how-to-serve-a-file-using-iron-router-or-meteor-itself) which describes how to serve a local file using Iron Router. I need to do the same, but instead of reading the file synchronously from disk, I need to get the file from S3 which is an asynchronous call.

The problem appears to be the fact that the `action` method has returned before the asynchronous `s3.getObject` completes giving me the following error.

`Error: Can't render headers after they are sent to the client.`

I'm assuming that Iron Router is generating the response for me when it realizes that I haven't handled the response in my `action` method, but I'm stumped about how to tell it to wait for my asynchronous call to finish.

Here is my code.

```js
Router.map(function () {
    this.route('resumeDownload', {
        where: 'server',
        path: '/resume/:_id',
        action: function () {
            var response = this.response;

            var candidate = Candidates.findOne(this.params._id);
            if (!candidate || !candidate.resumeS3Key) {
                // this works fine because the method hasn't returned yet.
                response.writeHead(404);
                return response.end();
            }

            var s3 = new AWS.S3();
            s3.getObject({Bucket: 'myBucket', Key: candidate.resumeS3Key}, function (err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    // this will cause the error to be displayed
                    response.writeHead(500);
                    return response.end();
                }
                // this will also cause the error to be displayed
                response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': data.ContentType});
                response.end(data.Body);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to solve this one myself. I needed to use a `future` in my `action` method.

Here is the working code.

```js
Router.map(function () {
    this.route('resumeDownload', {
        where: 'server',
        path: '/resume/:_id',
        action: function () {
            var response = this.response,
                candidate = Candidates.findOne(this.params._id);

            if (!candidate || !candidate.resumeS3Key) {
                response.writeHead(404);
                return response.end();
            }

            var Future = Npm.require('fibers/future'),
                s3 = new AWS.S3(),
                futureGetObject = Future.wrap(s3.getObject.bind(s3)),
                data = futureGetObject({Bucket: 'myBucket', Key: candidate.resumeS3Key}).wait();

            response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': data.ContentType});
            response.end(data.Body);
        }
    });
});
```