# Download File Link using iron-router version 1.0.0-pre2

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I am using bootstrap-3, collection-fs and iron-router. I have successfully created a download button before, but since upgrading to iron-router version 1.0.0-pre2, I have not been able to successfully replicate the download button.

```
<a href="{{this.url download=true}}" class="btn btn-primary">Download</a>
```

where `this.url` provides the url to the file. However iron-router tries to route the entire app to the file location rather then downloading the file. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because the route should be server side route
Check out this thread [How to serve a file using iron router or meteor itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21565991/how-to-serve-a-file-using-iron-router-or-meteor-itself)