# Download File With Iron-Router and CollectionFS

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

I have an iron:router route declared for when a user tries to download a file:

```
// File Download Route
Router.route('/download/:file', function () {
   // NodeJS request object
   var request = this.request;

   // NodeJS  response object
   var response = this.response;

  this.response.end('file download content\n');
  }, {where: 'server'}
```

);

as described in the iron:router docs (http://eventedmind.github.io/iron-router/#server-routing) . The file I pass into the route is the CollectionFS file object(https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-CollectionFS). How do I now get the application to actually trigger the download of the file. Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21565991/how-to-serve-a-file-using-iron-router-or-meteor-itself

Comment: @yoK0 I am trying to do it with a collectionFS object.