# Set content type in meteor + react router

Tags: meteor, react-router

i need to change content-type, is it possible to do this without iron-router or collectionFS.

P.S. i am using react-router

example how to do this with iron router:
[Meteor, generate and download file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26508881/meteor-generate-and-download-file)

Comment: ok,, i need to use WebApp https://docs.meteor.com/packages/webapp.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in server side:

```
import { WebApp } from 'meteor/webapp';
WebApp.connectHandlers.use("/files", function(req, res, next) {
    doc = find('get some data from where you want');
    const headers = {
        'Content-Type': doc.filetype,
        'Content-Disposition': "inline; filename=" + doc.filename
    };
    res.writeHead(200, headers);
    res.end(doc.data);
});
```