# Iron router serve a file to download

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, iron-router, meteor-blaze

### NOTE

---

I have already gone through the below implementations and am attempting something very similar, however, I'm unable to wrap my head over how to get it to work.

1. [How to serve a file using iron router or meteor itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21565991/1745073)
2. [How to serve static content (images, fonts etc.) using iron router](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21341291/1745073)
3. [Meteor, generate and download file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26508881/1745073)

---

**What I have:**

**An event that calles a meteor method.**

```
'click #export'(event){
        event.preventDefault();
       Meteor.call('getExportBundleFile',AutoForm.getFieldValue('selectFlowTemplates','flowTemplateSelector'),function(error,resp){

            Router.go('/text');    
        });
    }
```

**The meteor method that creates content for the file (File contains mongo records in json format)**

```
getExportBundleFile: function(flowTemplateNames){

        var username = Meteor.user().username;
        var filename = username + "_" + moment(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DD-HHMMss")+".ez";
         actualFlowTemplateContent = [];
        flowTemplateNames.forEach(function(flowTemplate){
            actualFlowTemplateContent.push(templates.findOne({flowTemplateName: flowTemplate}));
        });


         headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
            'Content-Disposition': "attachment; filename=" + filename
        };

        return filename
}
```

**A route defined in my server**

```
Router.route('/text', function() {
    // NodeJS request object
    var request = this.request;
    // NodeJS  response object
    var response = this.response;

    this.response.writeHead(200, headers);
    this.response.end(actualFlowTemplateContent);
}, {
    where: 'server'
});
```

**My problem**

The above scenario works well when I download a file once. Subsequent clicking of the button must let me download over and over again, however, it does nothing.

I have a feeling because I'm using `Router.go('/text')` in my client code which is redirecting it to `/text` although I don't see any changes in the address bar.
I can also substantiate the above since I'm able to download the file again, if I were to navigate away from the page and back to it again.

I am not sure how to fix this, can someone provide some pointers about this?