# How to use different directory to serve static assets?

Tags: meteor

Along with `app/public`, I would like to use another directory `app/other` to serve static assets, How can I do that?

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21565991/how-to-serve-a-file-using-iron-router-or-meteor-itself) is the only other way I'm aware of to accomplish this. If you find that answer acceptable, I'll mark this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meteor is designed to allow only `/public` folder to be public. You can do the [trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21565991/how-to-serve-a-file-using-iron-router-or-meteor-itself) proposed by @David Weldon but I guess it is a little overkill. I would advise you to use a sub-folder of `/public` like `/public/images` or `/public/fonts`?

Note that to refer these folder, you don't mention public, e.g. `url(/images/background.png)` or `url(/fonts/myfont.eot)`