# Add custom HTTP header in youtube-dl to force extracted direct link to file not to open, but download

Tags: python, youtube-dl

I need to add custom HTTP header to extracted direct link to file by youtube-dl so it won't open once clicked in browser, but download. I was going to use solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31362814/force-links-to-mp4-files-to-download-instead-of-opeaning-in-browser-using-meteor), but there might be easier solution. There is a option in [youtube-dl Workarounds](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#workarounds):

```html
--add-header FIELD:VALUE         Specify a custom HTTP header and its value, separated by a colon ':'. You can use this option multiple times
```

My question is what header to write as a FIELD and VALUE in terminal to force direct link to file to download by default.

```html
youtube-dl -g --add-header FIELD:VALUE https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9Q7Vr3yQYWQ
```

**EDIT:**
To better explain what I'm trying to accomplish, I execute the following command from application on server:

```html
youtube-dl -g URL
```

and return output, what is direct link to video file, to client for user to download. Problem is that by default, browser opens the file and not starts download. By changing header of the file, you can force browser to download. My question is that if it applies to direct links too and if so, how to add header in youtube-dl script to force the link to trigger download.

HTML 5 solution that works only in Chrome and Firefox, is not good enough.

```html
<a href="url" download="filename"></a>
```

Comment: I'm confused. Why are you trying to add a header to the call to `youtube-dl`? Running `youtube-dl` won't open your browser on the file it downloads. That's not how it works. Are you trying to change what your browser does when you click on a youtube URL?

Comment: Ah. Where else do you need this to work besides Chrome and Firefox? Presumably IE? But what versions? You can't, with youtube-dl, control what the browser does when you click the link it returned. That behavior is up to the browser with respect to the URL it saw and the result is received from the remote server. The URL itself doesn't control the action. (The HTML seems to be able to with that `download` attribute though apparently.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taken from [this youtube-dl issue](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/5960). For non-dash formats (for example if you use `-f best` when calling youtube-dl) if you add `&title=something` to the url you get with youtube-dl their servers add the following header to the response: `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="something.mp4"`, forcing the browser to download it as `something.mp4`.

Comment: Didn't work for me. `youtube-dl -f 135+140 "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2t8dBHrjReI&title=something"`. Added headers before executing command. tried with **exec()**, **shell_exec()**, **passthru**.
Am i missing something?

Comment: No it works, just add it the first time you retrieve the video links from youtube then the second time when you download the video stream link.