# Iron router on action using Meteor.call throws writeHead is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, iron-router

I'm trying to write a buffer which returns from server to the client response.

Therefore, I've defined a route which runs to fetch file on `action` function:

```
Router.route('/download/:blabla', {
    name: 'download',
    action: function () {
       var that = this.response;
       Meteor.call('downloadFile', blabla, function (err, result) {
           // error check etc.
           var headers = {
               'Content-type' : 'application/octet-stream',
               'Content-Disposition' : 'attachment; filename=' + fileName
           };
           that.writeHead(200, headers);
           that.end(result);
        }
    }
});
```

This throws:

> Exception in delivering result of invoking 'downloadFile': TypeError:
>   that.writeHead is not a function

Without Metoer.call it works...

I'm using nodejs stream to fetch buffer on server side function and it works.

Thanks in advance

Comment: why don't you try to set `var that = this` and `that.response.writeHead(...)`

Comment: It didnt help as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using a server side only route in IR? i.e. make the route accessible on the server only with `{where:"server"}' to avoid having to do a method call as per example below from [here](http://www.curtismlarson.com/blog/2015/09/11/meteor-render-pdf-iron-router/) (note serving the file int his example requires the addition of the meteorhacks:npm package as per comments but you might be able to avoid this...):

```
Router.route("/file/:fileName", function() {
  var fileName = this.params.fileName;

  // Read from a file (requires 'meteor add meteorhacks:npm')
  var filePath = "/path/to/pdf/store/" + fileName;
  var fs = Meteor.npmRequire('fs');
  var data = fs.readFileSync(filePath);

  this.response.writeHead(200, {
    "Content-Type": "application/pdf",
    "Content-Length": data.length
  });
  this.response.write(data);
  this.response.end();
}, {
  where: "server"
});
```

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21565991/how-to-serve-a-file-using-iron-router-or-meteor-itself