# Images in public directory of Meteor JS are not loading

Tags: javascript, image, meteor, directory, static-files

I have followed a doc that proposed creating a public directory to hold images, fonts and js files. It reads the fonts, but does not display images but when I manually navigate to the images on the browser it displays,  what could be wrong? directory structure:

```
app_root->public->assets->img->1.jpg
```

on the browser: http://localhost:3000/assets/img/portfolio/1.jpg which displays the image. What wrong am I to right?

Comment: What does your image tag look like? This kind of errors in often due to the use of relative paths instead of absolute ones.

Comment: Make sure `/public` is not in your `img` path - `/public` gets mapped to `/`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use absolut links, use relative! Meteor build css, scss, js, image files. File structure:

```
/
/public
/public/img/
/public/img/1.jpg
```

And try this:

```
<img src="/img/1.jpg" alt="First image">
```

If you want to reach it from outside, you have to set it in the router.

Previous answer: [How to serve static content (images, fonts etc.) using iron router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21341291/how-to-serve-static-content-images-fonts-etc-using-iron-router)

Server static example: https://gist.github.com/goje87/8aa5c04bf3b0f5de907d